# Is it safe to encode regex input by user for use with File::Find::Rule?

Tags: perl, utf-8

I am working on an application that takes a regex as input from the user at the command line, and then applies that regex to find certain files under the current directory. The application support UTF-8 input, and should be able to find UTF-8 encoded file names. Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use Encode ();
use File::Find::Rule;

system 'touch', 'aæ', 'bæ', 'aa'; # some test files, 

my $pat = 'æ$';
my $pat_encode = encode( $pat );
run_test( $pat_encode, 'With encode()' );
run_test( $pat, 'Without encode()' );
my $pat2 = '[æ]$';
my $pat2_encode = encode( $pat2 );
run_test( $pat2_encode, 'With encode()' );

sub encode {
    return Encode::encode('UTF-8', $_[0], Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
}

sub run_test {
    my ( $pat_encode, $test_str ) = @_;

    say $test_str;
    say '-' x length $test_str;
    say "";
    my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->name( qr/$pat_encode/ )->in('.');
    for (@files) {
        $_ = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $_, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC );
    }

    say $_ for @files;
}
```

The output is:

```
With encode()
-------------

aæ
bæ
Without encode()
----------------

With encode()
-------------

aæ
bæ
```

I would expect that the last regex `[æ]$` would not work after being encoded, since the `æ` will expand to two bytes `0xC3A6`, but somehow, it seems Perl knows that the regex is encoded in UTF-8 and does some magic to have it work.

I wonder if someone knows why the latter example is working, and if there are any other cases where encoding the regex would not work? ( So I am trying to decide if I can use [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) or if I should switch to [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) which would allow me to avoid having to encoding the regex.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it is not safe to encode the regex. Specifically if a bracket expression is followed by one or more characters, the regex may select unwanted files. The reason is that only a single of the bytes in the UTF-8 encoded version will be matched by the bracket expression.  Consider the following modification of my script:

```
system 'touch', 'aæ', 'aæ1', 'aa'; # some test files, 

my $pat = 'æ.$';
my $pat_encode = encode( $pat );
run_test( $pat_encode, 'With encode()' );
run_test( $pat, 'Without encode()' );
my $pat2 = '[æ].$';
my $pat2_encode = encode( $pat2 );
run_test( $pat2_encode, 'With encode()' );
```

Now this should only return the file `aæ1`, however the `$pat2` regex will also return `aæ` since only the first of the two bytes of the encoded `æ` will be used up by the bracket expression, leaving the last byte to be matched by trailing `.` in `$pat2`.

The output is:

```
 With encode()
-------------

aæ1
Without encode()
----------------

With encode()
-------------

aæ
aæ1
```

The solution seems to be to use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) instead :

```
use File::Find ();

system 'touch', 'aæ', 'aæ1', 'aa'; # some test files, 

my $pat = '[æ].$';
my $files = find_files( $pat );

say $_ for @$files;

sub decode {
    return Encode::decode('UTF-8', $_[0], Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC );
}

sub find_files {
    my ( $pat ) = @_;

    my @files;
    File::Find::find( sub { wanted( $pat, \@files ) }, '.' );
    return \@files;
}

sub wanted {
    my ( $pat, $files ) = @_;
    my $name = decode( $_ );
    my $full_name = decode( $File::Find::name );
    push @$files, $full_name if $name =~ /$pat/;
}
```

The output is now correct:

```
./aæ1
```

**Update**:

In fact, `File::Find::Rule` can be used after all. Simply use the `exec` rule instead of the `name` rule:

```
my $pat = '[æ].$';
my $files = find_files( $pat );

say for @$files;

sub find_files {
    my ( $pat ) = @_;

    my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->exec( sub { wanted( $pat ) } )->in('.');
    for (@files) {
        $_ = decode( $_ );
    }
    return \@files;
}

sub wanted {
    my ( $pat ) = @_;
    my $name = decode( $_ );
    return ( $name =~ /$pat/ ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The output is now:

```
aæ1
```